# Unsure about downloading the contents of the file in firebase storage via react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-storage

As what I want to do is to read a particular folder that contains multiple file and displaying the content from all the files on the app. I am currently able to get each of the URL from each of the files. But I am unsure on the downloading of the content.

To download the data in the file. With the reference to the documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url:

```
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = (event) => {
          const blob = xhr.response;
          };
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          xhr.send();
```

I added the above in my code:

```
const listRef = sRef(storage, paramKey)
  // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        // All the prefixes under listRef.
        // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
      });
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        // All the items under listRef.
        console.log(itemRef)
        getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url =>{
          console.log(url)
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = (event) => {
          const blob = xhr.response;
          };
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          xhr.send();
          console.log(xhr)
        }))
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      console.log(error)
    });
```

I tried to `console.log(xhr)` and I got 4 of such logs:

[image]

How am I going to use this information to get the exact content out to display? I tried searching on youtube guides on explaining the codes to download the file but I couldnt find any. Can anyone explain how this works and how can I extract the content of my files from the above logs to display?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the blob it gets from Storage here: `const blob = xhr.response;`. Those are the contents of the remote file, so you'll need to process them in however is fit for your use-case.

Comment: If the screenshot is the contents of my remote file, why do I not see ```Awesome``` in ASCII values? If you remembered, I had a post about the files I have been saving are converting to ASCII values by itself. I dont see it here though. From the docs you have linked me in my other posts, is the ```CORS``` thing I am suppose to do? I see something about ```getBytes()``` that ```Downloads the data at the object's location```. Or is it something esle? I'm quite confuse on this

Comment: What I want to do is just if I have a number of files. Example file content 1: The word - Awesome. File number 2 : The word - Nice. File number 3: The word - Bad. I just want to extract ```Awesome```, ```Nice```, ```Bad``` and display out

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen